# ActiveRecord find with include

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Let's say that Person `has_many` Addresses, and with this query I can go through the loop and use addresses for that peoples.

```
@people = Person.find(:all, :include => :addresses)
```

But, I want to include ONLY addresses where the user_id = 1 for example.

How to build query to do that?

P.S. New to RoR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@people = Person.find(:all, :include => :addresses, :conditions => ['user_id=?',params[:user_id]])
```

Make note that when you include you can only have one column of each or rails will give you an error about ambiguous find conditions.

Comment: With this conditions I get query that make search for user_id in Person table, not in Addresses table :| 
I need to pass conditions for filtering included addresses table.

Comment: try ':joins => :addresses', instead of ':includes'

Comment: As of RoR 3.2 it would be : @people = Person.all(:include => :addresses, :conditions => ['user_id=?', params[:user_id]])